# Routing to a Location on the Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have several custom routes in my rails 3.0 app, the simplest one of which is.

```
match "*user", "profile#index", :via => :get
```

Because of that route physical locations on the server are killed. As an example.

```
/images/rails.png
```

tries to route to the images user.

I also have to be able to setup where people access

```
/<username>/archive.zip
```

So

```
/buddy/archive.zip
```

Where the archive.zip is a physical file on the server that has been generated and put there. How can I achieve this in my routing.

For the later I have an actual folder structure in a root folder for `/<username>/archive.zip` so I was thinking somem sort of symlink would be easy, but without being able to hit physical locations on the server. I am kind of stuck/confused.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to have any static assets get handled by your web server before hitting your rails stack. This is generally done by setting the document root in your webserver to the public/ directory within your rails app to serve your static images/css/js.

This is greatly preferred over allowing Rails to serve static assets because web servers are much faster at handling these sorts of requests, and your not tying up your rails processes for these requests, which are often limited to less than a handful.

Comment: that is how I have my server setup, but using webrick for dev work I am not sure how it handles it.

Comment: alright I have more information. I have setup a test server and deployed what I have. I setup passenger to hit public like normal, still having same problem.

Comment: Marking as answer since I realized when I copied the image to the folder it didn't actually copy the image. I moved it into the images folder and all worked well, and there goes a day of work because of it.

Comment: The setting for changing whether or not rails serves static assets from public is serve_static_assets, you should see it in config/environments/product.rb and it should be set to false. In development mode it's true so that webrick can serve these assets without requiring a webserver be in front of it.